# Creating an unindent algorithm using boost::range

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, gtkmm, boost-range

I'm creating an unindent algorithm for a text-editor. I've managed to obtain the range to operate on, but when I want to do the Gtk::TextBuffer::erase, it fails:

```
void unindentSelection(const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::TextBuffer> &buffer)
{
    Gtk::TextBuffer::iterator start, end;

    buffer->get_selection_bounds(start, end);

    auto selRange = boost::make_iterator_range(start, end);
    auto buffRange = boost::make_iterator_range(buffer->begin(), buffer->end());

    auto prevRangeRev = boost::make_iterator_range(buffRange.begin(), selRange.begin()) | boost::adaptors::reversed;
    auto prevRangeLineRev = boost::find<boost::return_begin_found>(prevRangeRev, '\n');
    auto prevRangeLine = prevRangeLineRev | boost::adaptors::reversed;

    auto afterRange = boost::make_iterator_range(selRange.end(), buffRange.end());
    auto afterRangeLine = boost::find<boost::return_begin_found>(afterRange, '\n');

    auto exSelRangeAux = boost::join(prevRangeLine, selRange);
    auto exSelRange = boost::join(exSelRangeAux, afterRangeLine);

    show_range(exSelRange);

    while (true)
    {
        auto spaceRange = boost::find_if<boost::return_begin_found>(exSelRange, findNonspaceNL);

        if (boost::distance(spaceRange))
        {
            buffer->erase(spaceRange.begin(), spaceRange.end());
        }
    }
}
```

TextEditor.cpp:501:31: error: no viable conversion from 'boost::range_detail::join_iterator >, Gtk::TextIter, unsigned int, unsigned int, boost::iterators::bidirectional_traversal_tag>, Gtk::TextIter, unsigned int, unsigned int, boost::iterators::bidirectional_traversal_tag>' to 'const iterator' (aka 'const Gtk::TextIter')
                buffer->erase(spaceRange.begin(), afterRangeLine.end());
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/textiter.h:145:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'boost::range_detail::join_iterator >, Gtk::TextIter, unsigned int, unsigned int, boost::iterators::bidirectional_traversal_tag>, Gtk::TextIter, unsigned int, unsigned int, boost::iterators::bidirectional_traversal_tag>' to 'const Gtk::TextIter &' for 1st argument
class TextIter
      ^
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/textiter.h:145:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'boost::range_detail::join_iterator >, Gtk::TextIter, unsigned int, unsigned int, boost::iterators::bidirectional_traversal_tag>, Gtk::TextIter, unsigned int, unsigned int, boost::iterators::bidirectional_traversal_tag>' to 'Gtk::TextIter &&' for 1st argument
class TextIter
      ^
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/textbuffer.h:378:34: note: passing argument to parameter 'range_begin' here
  iterator erase(const iterator& range_begin, const iterator& range_end);

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had to create an iterator type that contained a templated 'Iterator it' inside (which in my case is the Gtk::TextIter), using 'boost::iterator_facade'. All operations to the iterator where forwarded to 'it', except the operator*(), that just gave the plain iterator. So the erasing was done in this way:

```
buffer->erase(*spaceRange.begin(), *spaceRange.end());
```

This new type of iterator will be very useful manipulating ranges. Not sure this is the best solution, but works.